# Appending a Canvas Element to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I’m trying to use `appendChild` here to call up a canvas and make a program like MS Paint and here I'm trying to just 'draw' with my mouse.

I have tried to change the height/width of this to only be 500x500 and appear in-between a div that I need to call too in a div.

I cannot seem to understand why this is not working correctly.

Can someone please help?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.style.margin = 0; 
canvas.style.position = 'fixed'; 
resize(); 

var pos  = { x: 0, y: 0 }; 

canvas.addEventListener('resize', resize); 
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw); 
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition); 
canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition); 

//what would be the new positions from the "mouse" event. 

function setPosition(e) 
{ 
    pos.x = e.clientX; 
    pos.y = e.clientY;
}

function resize()
{ 
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
} 

function draw(e) 
{ 
    if (e.buttons! ==1) return; 

    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.lineWidth = 5; 
    ctx.lineCap = 'round'; 
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); 
    setPosition(e); 
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); 

    ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using like this.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

`document.getElementById('idName')` is used to select an existing element. It doesn't create a new one.